# Listen for a key press with Powershell, but don't wait for it

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that toggles the caps lock key periodically, but I also want to be able to toggle the script because it causes some issues with other functionality (like alt tabbing, and rolling over windows in the task bar to see a preview)

The script I have so far is

```
:outer while($true){
    do{ 
    echo "Toggle with F12";
    $x = [System.Console]::ReadKey() 
    }while( $x.Key -ne "F12" )
    while($true){
        $wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
        $wsh.SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')
        sleep 0.3
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wsh)
        Remove-Variable wsh
        if ($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable) {
            $key = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()
            if($key.Key -ne "F12"){
                break outer
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The script waits for the user to press F12, and then once they press F12 I want it to start toggling the caps lock key ever 0.3 seconds until the user presses F12 again. Ideally, I want this to happen in the background, but I don't know if that's possible. I don't want the user to have to have the console window open to toggle the script.

The way this runs now, after the user presses F12 the script will toggle capslock once and then exit. If I remove the conditional after Remove-Variable, the script will run as I want it to except the only way it can be stopped is if the console window is closed.

Comment: Have you tried using if([Console]::KeyAvailable)

Comment: @MickyB I just tried something with that, but the script doesn't terminate. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my conditional that checks what key was pressed.

       `if([Console]::KeyAvailable){
            $key = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()
            if($key -eq "F12"){
                break outer
            }
        }`

I'm storing the key press in $key and then trying to see if $key -eq "F12" but this does nothing.

Comment: KeyAvailable has a bug, if you press alt-Tab it returns true and then ReadKey hangs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a try. BTW I changed the sleep to 1 second so it doesn't flash capslock too much while testing:

```
$continue = $true
while($continue)
{

    if ([console]::KeyAvailable)
    {
        echo "Toggle with F12";
        $x = [System.Console]::ReadKey() 

        switch ( $x.key)
        {
            F12 { $continue = $false }
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        $wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
        $wsh.SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')
        sleep 1
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wsh)| out-null
        Remove-Variable wsh
    }    
}
```

Comment: I had to make a minor change so that it wouldn't exit when toggled off, but yes, this is good. Do you know if there's any way to make it listen in the background so it can be toggled without the console window being the focus?

Comment: You can create a hook (via SetWindowsHookEx) to capture keyboard events even if you don't have focus. However I don't know if you can achieve that natively in Powershell. You might have to do it in C# and add-type your code.

Comment: @MickyBalladelli Were hooks still usable in 2014? I remember that problem started with Windows Vista and our company has completely given up with it when Windows 7 was released.

Answer (score 3):

```
add-type -Path '.\documents\WindowsPowerShell\VISE_WinKeyboardHook.dll'
$KeyboardInterceptor = new-object VISE.WinKeyboardHook.KeyboardInterceptor
function HandleKeyDown($keyId)
{
    write-host $keyID.KeyCode
    if($keyID.KeyCode -eq "Escape"){
        $KeyboardInterceptor.StopCapturing()
    }
}
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier KeyDown -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$keyevent = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $KeyboardInterceptor -EventName KeyDown -SourceIdentifier KeyDown -Action {HandleKeyDown($event.sourceEventArgs)}
$KeyboardInterceptor.StartCapturing()
```

Here is a C# assembly which provides event for global keyboard events.
https://ianmorrish.wordpress.com/v-ise/keyboard-hook/
Advantage of this is that it is non-blocking and also works in ISE.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: link to a DLL is broken

Comment: Updated link on page above