# How to send text/string when key is pressed powershell

Tags: powershell, automation

I want to make macros using function keys to improve my workflow but the code below doesnt work, i think its quite self explanatory, while the code is running if i press X key, a different text is sent.

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;  
# choose the key you are after
$key = [System.Windows.Input.Key]::LeftCtrl
$isCtrl = [System.Windows.Input.Keyboard]::IsKeyDown($key)    
while ($true)
{
if ($isCtrl)
{
    $wshell.SendKeys('Thank you for using the service.')
}
}
```

The code above doesnt work. But if i only use the code below it does send the string as expected.

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; 
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('Digital service desk')
```

Comment: You never update the value of `$isCtrl` after entering the loop. Move the `$isCtrl = [System.Windows.Input.Keyboard]::IsKeyDown($key)` line to right after `while($true){`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listen for a key press with Powershell, but don't wait for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593200/listen-for-a-key-press-with-powershell-but-dont-wait-for-it)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that worked, i just changed the [System.Windows.Input.Keyboard]::IsKeyDown($key) to inside de if ( here ) and added a couple sleep and im not having any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) i was not updating the value of $isCtrl inside the loop. I'll now post the code if anyone wants to use it.

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;



Add-Type -AssemblyName WindowsBase
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore


while ($true)
{
if ([System.Windows.Input.Keyboard]::IsKeyDown([System.Windows.Input.Key]::F2))
{
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('Message after pressing F2')
} elseif ([System.Windows.Input.Keyboard]::IsKeyDown([System.Windows.Input.Key]::F4)){
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('Message after pressing F4')
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You keep checking the same value inside the loop since `$isCtrl` is never assigned to after entering the loop.

Change to:

```
while ($true)
{
  $isCtrl = [System.Windows.Input.Keyboard]::IsKeyDown($key)    
  if ($isCtrl)
  {
    $wshell.SendKeys('Thank you for using the service.')
  }
}
```

So that you re-check whether control is pushed down every time.